# Update query reaching SQL server but does not update the record and returns no error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This is the issue:

I have a table in which update queries are failing.

When a user clicks on a delete button in the application, RowStatus should be set as 0 instead of 1, the data type is bit.
Using SQL profiler, we can see that the update query is reaching the SQL server, but it is not running there - it does not return any exception to the application.
We are using the PK of the table to identify the row to be updated.
We are able to successfully insert values into table from application via web server, only the update queries fail.
We have muplitple tables in the application - but the issue is only for this table.
We use entity framework for updating the table.

Can any one please help  ?

This is the table structure:

```
[dbo].[TableName](
[PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ForeignKey1] [int] NOT NULL,
[ForeignKey2] [int] NOT NULL,
[RowStatus] [bit] NULL,
[CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
[CreationDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[UpdatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
)
```

This is the query i saw in profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[TableName]
SET [RowStatus] = @0, [UpdatedBy] = @1, [UpdatedDate] = @2
WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @3)
',N'@0 bit,@1 int,@2 datetime2(7),@3 int',@0=0,@1=999,@2='2018-05-02 
05:20:16.2795067',@3=30
```

**Update: It started working after i changed the dbcontext.savechanges() instead of dbcontext.savechangesasync() to save the changes to entity.
Has anyone faced this issue before ?**

Comment: If you see it reaching the server using sqlprofiler - it is running....  are you sure the web server account has update privilages on that table?

Comment: Can you please share the query and the table structure on which you are executing the query?

Comment: Yes, it has update  permission, because update is failng for only one table.

Comment: Make sure you have no catch blocks swallowing exceptions (as in, you *are* getting an error but you don't see it). It might be helpful to set debugger break when an exception is thrown so you see it no matter what. Another thought: fire up SSMS and fire the query by hand with the same user

Comment: Not enough information, and sounds a bit harry potterish to me if you are doing things right

Comment: What *else* is different on the web server from your machine? Are you definitely using the same username/connection string where it works compared to where it doesn't? Can you run a SQL client on the web server and try it from there to eliminate your own code? (Are you absolutely, definitely sure you're in the right database? I've seen people become very confused when they have, say, accidentally created a table with the same name in the `master`/default database but think they're updating the one in their own schema... The SQL looks perfect but the wrong table is being updated.)

Comment: The same query when ran from SSMS using app user will work.

Comment: Perhaps the update is being issued from a transaction that is not committed.

Comment: I agree with Dan, it sounds as though you have a transaction being rolled back. So while the original query is reaching SQL server ok and executing, its just being rolled back later on. You could prove the update is actually trying to execute by manually starting a transaction and locking the table/row being updated - the app should then hang and you will be able to see it waiting for locks until the manual txn is closed.

Comment: EnityFramework is used for committing the data. We call savechangesasync() of EF to commit the transcation.

Comment: The DBA found that transaction is getting rolled back. But we are not calling the code for rollback.Are you aware of any scenarios where EF will rollback the transcation automatically? We use generic repository for updating the DB, so the code for updating is same for all table, but facing issue in only one table.

Comment: @TheGeneral: I have updated the post, can you please check.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework try cleaning the project as some cache may stop your code to execute cleanly.

Comment: I re-deployed it multiple times. The issue still remains. savechangesasync() is the EF method use to commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add 'await' keyword in the method call.
That was causing this issue.